# Expandable SideBar Menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu

Can anyone suggest some jquery plugin or some tutorial for expandable side bar menu using

```
<ul> <li>
```

tags

Answer (score 1):

I don'tknow if there is any jQuery plugin doing it, but a litlle plain jQuery javascript would do the job. Combining, slideUp, slideDown effects.

However, I've used this in the past. 
(French link) http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/602-Creer-un-menu-accordeon-avec-jQuery.html